# Turning a linear sequence in a numpy array into a geometric progression sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logarithm

This is a question for all the really clever users of advanced Python out there. My input is a series of numbers in a Python numpy array. They are floating point values arranged in a linear sequence. I need to create a new geometric sequence where:

- the new first value = the original first value
- the new second value = the sum of original values two and three
- the new third value = the sum of original values four to seven
- the new fourth value = the sum of values eight to fifteen

I can of course do this by looping through the data but I need this processing to be done as quickly as possible - the arrays are huge. What is the fastest way to do this?

example:

```
12.0, 3.4, 9.2, 7.7, 4.9, 3.8, 6.9
```

should become:

```
12.0, 12.6, 23.3
```

Comment: Whoops, yes. I am not very numerate, sorry.

Comment: Changed the original text so that they third became the second and so on. Didn't know one could do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.add.reduceat` and `int.bit_length`.

Example:

```
# make example sequence
a = np.arange(100.0)

# form sums
np.add.reduceat(a,(1<<np.arange(a.size.bit_length()))-1)
# array([   0.,    3.,   18.,   84.,  360., 1488., 2997.])
```

This adds items 0; 1+2; 3+4+5+6; etc. which your example suggests is what you really want.

Comment: numpy really has everything

Comment: Wow, looks extremely concise. Yes, these are the sums I need. As I said above, my dyslexia affects my use of numbers as much as text, so sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from math import log, floor
a = [12.0, 3.4, 9.2, 7.7, 4.9, 3.8, 6.9]
print([sum(a[2**i-1:2**(i+1)-1]) for i in range(floor(log(len(a), 2)) + 1)])
```

This outputs:

```
[12.0, 12.6, 23.3]
```

The indices used for the sums are:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (3, 7), (7, 15), (15, 31), ...]
```

The last sum can be shortened when the length of the list isn't exact one less than a power of 2.

Comment: Thank you. Looks pretty concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
seq = [12.0, 3.4, 9.2, 7.7, 4.9, 3.8, 6.9]

r = 0       # this is the binary power (2^r)
g_seq = []  # list to contain your final answer
i = 0       # index of start position for summing at each iteration  

while i < len(seq):   # once i reaches the last element, stop looping
    n = 2**r          # number of elements to sum in each iteration
    j = i + n         # index of end position for summing
    r+= 1             # increment power for next iteration
    subseq = seq[i:j] # slice of your input sequence to be summed
    g_seq.append(sum(subseq))   # sum the slice and append to answer list
    i = j             # j becomes the i for the next iteration

print(g_seq)
--------------------
[12.0, 12.6, 23.300000000000004]
```

Edit: added comments

Comment: Will have to time all three now and see which is fastest.

Comment: Paul's numpy solution will almost certainly be the fastest and most memory efficient too, since numpy is optimised for all of that.

Comment: Ah, right. As I said, that will be important in this case. Thanks again.

Comment: Testing with a = np.arange(2.0**24-1.0) clearly shows the numpy solution is fastest (the last of the sums should be 105553103683584)